ExoPlayer (Media3) video is getting puzzled or scrambled while switching between tabs or click multiple times on the custom controller
I'm building an Android app using Modular and Clean architecture using Jetpack Compose. At some points using ExoPlayer to play videos.
I've a screen at the top has ExoPlayer, underneath the player I've a simple UI with Tabs.
While i switch between the tabs, videos are getting scrambled.

@Composable
internal fun LessonDetailsScreenRoute(
) {
    var selectedVideoUrl by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(dummyUrl) }
    var selectedTab by remember {
        mutableStateOf(LessonDetailsScreenTabs.CONTENT)
    }

    Column (modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        // Moving the player outside the recomposable part
        PlayerContainer(selectedVideoUrl)
        LessonDetailsScreen(
            selectedTab = selectedTab,
            onTabSelected = { newTab -> selectedTab = newTab },
        )
    }
}

@Composable
internal fun LessonDetailsScreen(
    selectedTab: LessonDetailsScreenTabs,
    onTabSelected: (LessonDetailsScreenTabs) -> Unit,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
    ) {


        // Lesson details AppBar
        LessonAppBar(chapterName = chapterName, lessonName = lessonName, onBackPressed = onBackPressed)

        // Tabs
        UtkorshoTabs(
            titles = lessonDetailsTabsTitle,
            tabIdentifier = LessonDetailsScreenTabs.entries,
            tabSelected = selectedTab,
            onTabSelected = onTabSelected
        )

        // Handle the selected tab
        when (selectedTab) {
            LessonDetailsScreenTabs.CONTENT -> {
                Text(text = "Content Tab")
            }
            LessonDetailsScreenTabs.QNA -> {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp)) // Another simple UI element
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
@Composable
fun PlayerContainer(videoUrl: String?) {
    // Isolate the player from the recompositions of other UI elements
   // RecorderPlayerScreen(videoUrl = videoUrl)

    val context = LocalContext.current

    // Keep the player instance stable across recompositions
    val playerInstance = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
            playWhenReady = true
        }
    }

    // Only prepare the player when the URL changes
    LaunchedEffect(videoUrl) {
        Log.d("PROBLEM_DIAGNOSIS", "Preparing player with URL: $videoUrl")
        videoUrl?.let {
            val mediaSource = createDataSource(it)
            playerInstance.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
            playerInstance.prepare()
        }
    }

    // Only dispose of the player when the entire screen is disposed
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            Log.d("PROBLEM_DIAGNOSIS", "Releasing player as screen is disposed")
            playerInstance.release()
        }
    }

    // Render the Player View
    AndroidView(
        factory = { ctx ->
            Log.d("PROBLEM_DIAGNOSIS", "PlayerView created")
            PlayerView(ctx).apply {
                player = playerInstance
            }
        },
        update = { view ->
            Log.d("PROBLEM_DIAGNOSIS", "PlayerView updated")
            view.player = playerInstance
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp)
    )
}

 when (selectedTab) {
            LessonDetailsScreenTabs.CONTENT -> {
               Box(modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp))
            }
            LessonDetailsScreenTabs.QNA -> {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp)) // Another simple UI element
            }
        }

If i don't keep anything inside the content and Qna, it does not create problems with the player.
If i keep only Box or Spacer, It does not create any problems with the player. But If i use a simple Text View it started creating the above issues.
